# Error ORA-00937 la funcion de grupo no es de grupo Unico

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta, necesito pasarla a ORACLE, me sale el siguiente mensaje Error ORA-00937 la funcion de grupo no es de grupo Unico:

```
Select count(1) + 
   (Select count(1) CONTEO1 
      From w0034_proceso_detalle 
     Where c0034_estado in(0,1)) CONTEO
 From w00891_ses_tablas
Where not exists (
          Select 1 
            From w0034_proceso_detalle 
           WHERE f_to_varchar(c0089_rowid)= c0034_llave)
```

Comment: oracle tambien usa SQL.. que quiere decir que en SQL funciona bien???

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT A.CONTEO FROM (SELECT SUM(T.CONTEO) CONTEO
       FROM (Select count(1) CONTEO From w00891_ses_tablas
             UNION 
             Select count(1) CONTEO From w0034_proceso_detalle Where c0034_estado in(0,1)
       )   T ) A,w00891_ses_tablas  Where not exists (
Select 1 From w0034_proceso_detalle WHERE f_to_varchar(c0089_rowid)= c0034_llave) GROUP BY CONTEO
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).